# $g(z)=z^2~$ What will $~g(y ̅_n )~$ converge to in probability?

Tags: continuity, self-learning

Another homework question here.

$~Y_1, Y_2, \cdots, Y_n~$ is i.i.d.

$$g(z)=z^2$$

What will $~g(y ̅_n )~$  converge to in probability?

I'm not sure if Slutsky Theorem has something to do with it.

I'm assuming its simply $~\mu~$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Wanted to start off with 'Hi guys', but it always got deleted.

Comment: What does the minus sign above the $y$ mean? That is, what is y ̅_n  and how does it relate to the i.i.d. random variables $\{Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, ...\}$?  Are you really talking about convergence in distribution, rather than convergence in probability? What is $\mu$?

Comment: It was meant to be y bar and then subscript n. I don't know how it got to that. I just started with this topic so I essentially regurgitated the entire question. And the question stated, "converge to in probability". I am assuming the answer to be mu.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your $\overline y_n$ is given by $\overline y_n=(Y_1+\cdots Y_n)/n$.

By the [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem) (which can be considered Slutsky's theorem's big sister) if $\overline y_n$ converges in probability to a constant $c$, then $g(\overline y_n)$ converges to $c^2$.
But without further info about the distribution of the $Y_i$ one does not know if such a $c$ exists.  If $E|Y_i|<\infty$, for instance, $c$ exists and is given by $c=EY_1$.  But if the $Y_i$ are Cauchy distributed (so $E|Y_i|=\infty$) no such $c$ exists.

Comment: About this continuous mapping theorem, I haven't learned it so I am not sure if the teacher would accept the inclusion of this theorem. But I still appreciate your answer.

Comment: The important thing is that your $g$ is continuous, which means this-and-that about $\epsilon$ and $\delta$; convergence in probability involves a $\delta$, as well, and you can fit these ingredients together to make a valid proof.